# Angular get attr undefined when pass to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the compile phase i have access to all the attrs element. so why when im passing this attr to function i get undefiened

here is the code and plunker:

```
.directive('test', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    compile: function(ele, attr) {

       var div = angular.element( '<div ng-show="someCond(attr.some)">directive</div>' );

       ele.append(div)

       return function(scope, ele, attr) {
         scope.someCond = function(name) {
          console.log(name);
           return name == 'john';

         }
       }

    }
  }
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ne4Z24VM1VmOcwAuUdCT?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done basically two mistakes.

The first the attribute need to be concatenated correctly, so this statement must be

`var div = angular.element( '<div ng-show="someCond('+attr.some+')">directive</div>' );`

Secondly the value provide in html should be added inside quotes, therefore h1 should be:

`<h1 test some="'john'">test</h1>`

See my plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/QctVj9utJ88Xss8O11ze?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. i chose your answer because i dont need to do extra work and assign attr to scope like @OXMO456 answer.

Comment: but why i need to write this way some=" 'john' " and when i get attr from linking function i can do this like that some="that"?

Comment: Since the `ng-show` expects and expression. Since you need to pass constant expression `''` are required. If we do not add `''` the expression expect the value to come from `$scope.john`

Answer (score 0):

did you try to wrap all your module with these?

```
;(function(window,angular,undefined){
    //code here
})(window,window.angular);
```

it's not such a big deal but closure is good :D

Comment: just a best practice for isolate your module code and preventing any error who can be cause by thirdparty code 

(sorry english is not my native language ;) )

Answer (score 0):

`attr` object is not availlable in the `scope`
You can do that in order to make the `attr` object available:

```
return function(scope, ele, attr) {
         scope.attr = attr;// look here
         scope.someCond = function(name) {
           console.log(name);
           return name == 'john';
         }
       }
```